# Something strange in C# - UInt32 vs Int32

Tags: c#, unsigned, signed

#### Background

I work in C# usually writing support programs for embedded projects.  I inherited a project from someone long gone, which is a program used by one of my customers to download and upload Intel Hex files via RS-232 to some of their boards.  The program worked fine for them for a number of years, but with the new board which I am working on it did not, and needed some modifications.

#### Problem

I opened the project, and found the issue.  The new board was producing some data at addresses in the range `0x90000000-0x9007FFFF`, and the C# code was using the `int` type for the address data; which is signed, which incorrectly handled addresses over `0x80000000`.  So far, so good.  But then I got cocky.

I decided to clean up the code, replacing all "int" with Int16/UInt16/Int32/UInt32, depending on the usage.  It took a while, but I figured it would make the code clearer and more understandable, and hopefully avoid any future bugs.

The code ceased to work.  It took me most of the day, and it boiled down to this line:

```
currseg = (HexSegment)hex_segments[HashEntry];
```

The type HexSegment is a struct (yes, struct, not a class),

```
public struct HexSegment
{
    UInt32 Address; // this is the fix I made, both were int
    UInt32 Buf_idx;
}
```

hex_segments is a HashTable.

finally, HashEntry was an "int", also made into an `UInt32`.

In the debugger I see this:

[image]

If you can't see the image, the value of HashEntry is `0x00000000`.
If I ask the debugger to see `hex_segments[0]`, I get a `MLV.HexSegment` with legitimate data.
If I ask the debugger to see `hex_segments[HashEntry]`, I get null!!

Changing `HashEntry` to `Int32` fixed the issue.

Like I said, I'm an embedded programmer.  To me, this is a big mystery.  Is there anybody who can explain why this is like this?

Comment: Is it `0x08000000` (int) or `0x80000000` (uint)?

Comment: I think that the problem was that you changed the data type of `HashEntry` from an `int` to a `uint`. However, you didn't change the code that inserts *into* the HashTable, and that was still an `int`. If you ask the debugger for `hex_segments[0U]`, you'll get null.

Comment: (As an aside, `int` is always identical to `Int32`, and `uint` is always identical to `UInt64`. General practice is to use `int`/`uint`, not `Int32`/`UInt32`)

Comment: HashTable isn't a generic type.  The key is an object.  Both `int` and `uint` are value types, so both can be used, but they are different, a boxed int of 0 is very different than a boxed uint of 0.  There isn't any way to convert between them.  My guess is that you are inserting something in as an int (which gets converted to a boxed int), and trying to fetch it with a uint (converted to boxed uint).  Even though they are both `zero`, they are not equal

Comment: Generic collections make life **_much_** less error prone.

Comment: @Flydog57 "There isn't any way to convert between them" -- strictly speaking, the `Convert` class has methods to. But that's not in any way relevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Hashtable is indexed by object not by int.

```
public virtual object this[object key] { get; set; }
```

so if an object was added with key 0 as Int32, it would be different than an object added with 0 as UInt32.

Have a look at this:

```
UInt32 index = 0;
Int32 index2 = 0;
Hashtable t = new Hashtable();

t.Add(index, new { name = "matt" });
t.Add(index2, new { name = "Matt" });

var obj = t[index];
var obj2 = t[index2];

Console.WriteLine(obj);
Console.WriteLine(obj2);
```

Comment: Just to add: the recommendation since C# 2 is to use a `Dictionary<UInt32, HexSegment>`. Because the compiler knows that the lookup is always done using a `UInt32`, it will make sure that you can't use anything except a `UInt32`.

Comment: At the same time, the documentation for Hastable `Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are organized based on the hash code of the key.` But if you call `GetHashCode()` on both index and index2, it both results in 0. So I am still unsure why that works.

Comment: They're organised by hash code, but there's still an `Equals` check in there, and a box int != a boxed uint, even if they have the same hash code.

Comment: I this this is what they call object disoriented :)  .

Comment: You'll hit the same in any dynamically-typed language. You're supposed to use the type system that's made available to you to help avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: Understood.  I was trying to make things "cleaner" ... the HashTable.Adds were all done using the current value of HashTable.Count, which of course missed my "cleanup" (I didn't start modifying system code), but the lines using it were indexed by need.  I now have HashEntry defined also as "int", with a comment explaining why.